# Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '$400,000.00' to data type int

Tags: sql-server

I have the following part of query that works fine:

```
CONVERT(varchar(15), CONVERT(money, AmountOfInsurance), 1) AS AmountOfInsurance
```

I want to prevent anounts that are equal to `0` to show up formated, just to show up: `0`, so I added this `CASE` statement but I get the following error:

```
CASE WHEN AmountOfInsurance > 0 THEN '$' + CONVERT(varchar(15), CONVERT(money, AmountOfInsurance), 1) ELSE 0 END AS AmountOfInsurance
```

Any idea?

Comment: [Case expressions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) need to return a single data type.  That means that all outputs should return an int or varchar, etc.  If you had a column in your result set (`AmountOfInsurance`) where some rows where int (0) and others varchar ('$400,000.00') SQL would not know what to do with it (ex `SELECT 1 + 0 AS [1], '1' + '0' AS [10];`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just another option (if 2012+) is Format() with a conditional format.

```
Declare @YourTable table (AmountOfInsurance money)
Insert Into @YourTable values
(400000),
(2500),
(0)


Select format(AmountOfInsurance,IIF(AmountOfInsurance>0,'$#,##0.00','0'))
 From @YourTable
```

Returns

```
$400,000.00
$2,500.00
0
```

Comment: Thanks! Great solution!

Comment: @user3378165 Happy it helped.

Answer (score 3):

Your `ELSE` should be `''` because you want to return a varchar. Now the CASE expression has two data types and INT takes precedence over varchar, that's why it tries to convert the varchar back to INT.

*Added for reference:*
[Data Type Precedence](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190309.aspx)

Comment: Thank you, that solved my issue! But @JohnCappelletti solution is much nicer, I wish I could accept two correct answers..

Answer (score 1):

Use the CAST function to cast

```
DECLARE @text AS NVARCHAR(10)

SET @text = '100$'
SELECT CASE WHEN AmountOfInsurance > 0 THEN CAST(@text AS MONEY) ELSE 0 END
```